# Google Contacts API's and scope?

Tags: google-contacts-api

Currently i'm trying to retrieve all of a users contact information as well as retrieve their unique User ID.

Our app needs to utilise a users google contacts and the user will sign in using google. Thus we require some way of identifying each unique user (most likely a unique user id provided by google)

Is this possible only using the google contacts API.

The initial call I make to retrieve an access token is:

"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=51672309258-94cnvnrkrverd72neakom9d3siscda5o.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http://localhost/lunch/oauth.php&scope=https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/&response_type=code"

However I do not believe the access token returned from this call has any information for user ID and, also, does not provide the permissions to retrieve User ID from the Google+ Api.

Is there anyway that one can obtain a unique user ID from the google contacts API? There are examples of obtaining a user id of the users contacts but I need to obtain the actual users ID (i.e. the user whose contacts I am obtaining)?

Does this require another scope or can this also be accomplished by using the contacts API?

Answer (score 0):

You can identify a user by his/her email address, which is unique AFAIK. When you issue requests to google contacts api you get a field in the xml which is called Id, that is the user's email address.

For example you could ask for all contacts and you would get an xml like [this](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#retrieving_all_contacts) .The Id field is what you want, and depending on the programming language, lib , etc you are using you can get it with your existing permissions. For example in C# and gdata you would do something like this(googleCredentials is supposed to be your object):

```
        var cr = new ContactsRequest(settings);
        var feed = cr.GetGroups();
        googleCredentials.Email = feed.AtomFeed.Id.Uri.Content;
```

Answer (score 0):

> Note: The special userEmail value default can be used to refer to the
>   authenticated user.

from the documentation [documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#retrieving_all_contacts). You may try the keyword `default` as userEmail.